# Dispatching to Faces Servlet from Servlet Filter?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I have two filters;
filter one with **/admin/** mapping
filter two with **.xhtml** mapping 
incoming request URI is /admin/home.xhtml 
when this request is executed the first filter is  worked .and second one is also worked after filter one.I want to dispatch request to faces Servlet after first servlets dofilter  is executed.

Comment: Any reason why you can't define `FacesServlet` *before* the second filter in your web.xml, making `FacesServlet` the second filter in the chain?

Comment: I use @webfilter annotations.should I change this and define each one in web xml as you said

Comment: Yes you should. You can define filter precedence using web.xml only

Comment: @kolossus: filters are invoked before servlets.

Comment: @BalusC, I don't know how or why I got the idea `FacesServlet` is a filter. Must be getting old

Comment: I just need skip second filter to the faces servlet depending on a method in first filter.